# Проблема кодировки xhtml2pdf не работает с кириллицей выводит вместо букв квадраты

Tags: python, django, utf-8, pdf, кириллица

html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{report_id}}</title>

    <style>
    @font-face { font-family: Arial; src: url("/static/fonts/arial.ttf"); }
    body{
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is the report page for {{name}}.You can download it in PDF format.</h1>
    <p>Этот текст написан на кириллице</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta debitis libero non porro aperiam inventore cumque delectus molestias, explicabo consequatur obcaecati sit harum repudiandae exercitationem, impedit veritatis iste nesciunt praesentium.</p>
    <h1> The amount is {{amount}}</h1>
    <h1> The ID is {{id}}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

utils.py:

```py
def fetch_pdf_resources(uri, rel):
    if uri.find(settings.MEDIA_URL) != -1:
        path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.MEDIA_URL, ''))
    elif uri.find(settings.STATIC_URL) != -1:
        path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.STATIC_URL, ''))
    else:
        path = None
    return path


def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), result)    
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

views.py:

```py
class GeneratePdf(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        employee_ = Employee.objects.get(id=1)
        employee_name = employee_.name
        data = {
        "name": employee_name, #you can feach the data from database
        "id": 18,
        "amount": 333,
        }       
        pdf = render_pdf('pdf/report.html', data)
        if pdf:
            response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
            filename = "Report_for_%s.pdf" %(data['id'])
            content = "inline; filename= %s" %(filename)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = content
            return response
        return HttpResponse("Page Not Found")
```

Comment: Тоже не могу решить. Мои действия идентичны с вашими (((
Пробую варианты разные но к сожалению безрезультатно ...